# How can I automatically set a different ValidationGroup for each instance of a user control?

Tags: asp.net, validation, user-controls

I have a user control that has multiple instances on a single page.

Is it possible to have each instance use a unique ValidationGroup?  I could expose a property, but I'm wondering if there's any way to do it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

No automatic way; you have to include a public ValidationGroup property in the user control code-behind, and assign that to every control in the UC.  This could be programmatic assignment, but it also might work in markup using a <%= %> approach, not 100% sure about that.

HTH.

Comment: You cannot use <%= %> to set the value of control properties, so that approach won't work.